# Umbraco - How do you search for CSS Stylesheets using the top search bar?

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

When you type into the search bar, it makes an AJAX call to SearchAll that returns Content, Media and Members.

Is there any other way to search for CSS stylesheets without modifying the source code? Or, if it is necessary to do so, is there an example to allow it to search the Stylesheets/Scripts directories?

Source Code for SearchAll:
https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/a3d4ccc062b94859e446b1206bf21f334577a35c/src/Umbraco.Web/Editors/EntityController.cs

Comment: you should raise it as a feature request in umbraco

Answer (score 0):

I would use CTRL+F and find in the html (if you've go that many stylesheets) as stylesheets don't show up in search.

Raise it as a feature request - more info here: https://our.umbraco.org/contribute/report-an-issue-or-request-a-feature